# Triggered Send does not send SMS from RST API even if response is succes

Tags: marketing-cloud

we are trying to send the sms we received ok status but the sms does not reach the recipient

```
{
  "definitionKey": "teste",
  "recipient": {
    "contactKey": "teste@gmail.com",
    "to": "+5511945522897"
  },
    "subscriptions": {
    "resubscribe": true
  }

}
```

Comment: are they subscribed? you only have the resubscribe flag here

Comment: probably he is not subscribed, is there any field that I can enter if he is not subscribed?

Comment: there is a subscribe flag

Answer (score 0):

In addition to EazyE's question in the comments (are they subscribed), you should also observe requirements to the formatting of the mobile number used in Mobile Connect:

- Example of correctly formatted number: **4522334455**
- Hence no preceeding **+** symbol
- Country code, i.e. **45** for Denmark
- No whitespaces in the phone number